Office Script Error: The button cannot run because the script was unshared. Contact the owner to share it again
To the Office Script team.
I'm running into a weird issue with office scripts. I have an office script that I added to a spreadsheet (anyone who has the spreadsheet can run it). The office script is saved to a service account in OneDrive and added to the spreadsheet logged in as that account in Excel. We do this because we need to make external API calls and can't use a SharePoint site. I made an update to the script (it's still shared). However, after this update, it will run the first time you open the spreadsheet fine, but after the first run it gives the error: "The button cannot run because the script was unshared. Contact the owner to share it again." If you close the spreadsheet and reopen, it will work once again and subsequent button clicks will throw an error. The same applies to running the script in the automation panel.
I'm hesitant to try any sort of removing and adding the script back because I don't want to break the link with all the existing spreadsheets.

Sorry to hear you're running into this issue! This is a known bug and is on our team's backlog to fix (internal tracking: 8958542). I'll follow up once there are further updates.

This issue appears to have been resolved now - let me know if you're still having trouble?
